# Run shiny app outside of Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

So I was being clever I thought and I created a cool shiny app. But the app reads from local files and so I can't deploy it on shinyapps.io. I can of course run it in RStudio but then I can't do anything else with RStudio while it is running!  I'm wondering what my options are.

Comment: Just put your files in your app folder, they should be deployed as well

Comment: Yes, but I need to update the files regularly. That would require redeploying daily -- I guess that's a possibility though.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also load them from dropbox

Comment: Do you mean that I can save to the shinyapps.io through dropbox?

Comment: From your desktop, your master file is syncronized with dropbox, and you then read it from your shiny app

Comment: OK, yes, this seems like a possibility for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Host the shiny app and the data somewhere you control (i.e. your own server with `shiny-server` installed);
- Host the shiny app on shinyapps.io and host the data somewhere you control (Dropbox, AWS S3, your own file server) - have the app read from there;
- Have the shiny app (hosted wherever) go and collect the data itself - whatever you're doing to the data then storing it locally, have the app do that.